# Add Argument to Array: Autofocus to Woocommerce Login Field

Tags: wordpress, input, filter, woocommerce, autofocus

Heyo!
Currently on the woocommerce login page, the first input form for Billing (first name) has autofocus="autofocus," which means the page jumps to that spot each time it loads.

The billing section, though, is a bit down on my page, so it skips the above-the-fold content. I have a login form above it (woocommerce_login_form) to which I want to add 'autofocus' => 'autofocus' globally.

```
function woocommerce_login_form( $args = array() ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'message'  => '',
        'redirect' => '',
        'hidden'   => false,
    );

    $args = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    wc_get_template( 'global/form-login.php', $args );
}
```

I tried my own at it, but failed exceedingly, with:

```
function woocommerce_login_form( $args ) {
    $defaults = array (
        'message'  => '',
                'redirect' => '',
                'hidden'   => false,
                'autofocus' => 'autofocus'
        );
    return apply_filters('woocommerce_login_form', $defaults);
}
```

and with this

```
add_filter('woocommerce_login_form', 'autofocus_login_form', 10, 1);
function autofocus_login_form( $args ) {
    $args = array (
        'message'  => '',
                'redirect' => '',
                'hidden'   => false,
                'autofocus' => 'autofocus'
        );
    return $args;
}
```

Is it possible to add that parameter to the default woocommerce login form?

Sincerely,
Js

Answer (score 0):

I realized that, while I didn't know what I was doing with filters, I could just edit woocommerce/templates/global/form-login.php (onto my theme) and add

autofocus="autofocus" in the input html.